# HR Styling in Internet Explorer

Tags: css

I am a novice when it comes to CSS.  Have a small problem - the following code looks great in Firefox and Chrome, but not so much in IE (big surprise!).  The image is basically hidden behind the double-line hr.  Is there something I should try differently?

```
hr.style-eight {
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
border: none;
border-top: medium double #333;
color: #333;
text-align: center;
}

hr.style-eight:after {
content:url("/web_images/wheat_icon.png");  
display: inline-block;
position: relative; 
top: -1.25em;  
padding: 0 0.25em;
background: white;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you make [**jsbin demo**](http://jsbin.com)

Comment: By the way, use (lorempixel)[http://lorempixel.com] for the image.

Comment: I think I did this right: http://jsbin.com/kepigekola/1/edit?html,css,output